# Given a dataset of hourly data, how can I quickly find the average daily value?

Tags: excel-formula

For example, if I have a data set that looks like this (except has 365 days):

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd5yW.png)

I know I can manually use =average(B1:B23) and then manually increase the lower bound and upper bound by 24, but that is very tedious to do that 365 times. Is there a faster way to do this?

I could also do this easily in MATLAB, but it'd just be nice if there was a quick way to do it in Excel without importing the data into MATLAB, running a script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured this out if anyone else is looking for something like this. It's actually really easy if you use the OFFSET() function inside of your AVERAGE() function. Answer below:

=AVERAGE(OFFSET($B$2,24*(ROW()-2),0):OFFSET($B$25,24*(ROW()-2),0))

Keep in mind this answer assumes your data starts on B2 (so you have headers). The ROW() function just returns number of the row you are so. So, for example, if you typed =ROW() on cell B36, the cell's output would be 36.

The trick behind the formula is that when you drag down the above formula, the value of the ROW() function will increase by 1 every time which increases your reference points in your AVERAGE() formula by 24.

Comment: How does your formula return daily average? Looks to me like it returns an average of a span of four days. Regardless of the offset, your formula always returns an average of 96 cells, but if each cell represents hourly data, then wouldn't it return an average of four days, not one day?

Comment: Whoops, yes, fixed